# changing chrome prefs in `ruby` after starting the browser

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I have created a browser using

`@prefs = {download: { prompt_for_download: false, default_directory: "#{Dir.home}/new2" }   }

Watir::Browser.new :chrome, prefs: @prefs`

and when my script runs, it initiates another window while clicking Print option on Chrome

I want to change the `prefs` of the opened window to `@prefs` once it opens

Is there any way of writing it in `ruby`, `watir`, `page-object`

I have no idea how to change the `prefs` of newly opened window

Answer (score 0):

Those things can only be set at the time of browser instantiation. They are the parameters used by the browser driver when creating the session and can not be changed on an active season.